# MS Chart Control Exploded Pie Does Not

Tags: asp.net, charts

I have a pie chart and I want to "explode" a highlighted slice.

Using the following:

```
var qCounts = (from request in qCategory 
   group request by new { request.Category, request.Subcategory } into g 
             orderby g.Count() descending
                select new { 
                    g.Key.Category, 
                    g.Key.Subcategory,
                    CategoryCouplet = g.Key.Category + " - " + g.Key.Subcategory,
                             Count = g.Count() }).Take(10);

 mscPain.DataSource = qCounts;
 mscPain.Series["Pain Areas"].XValueMember = "CategoryCouplet";
 mscPain.Series["Pain Areas"].YValueMembers = "Count";
 mscPain.Series["Pain Areas"]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Disabled";
 mscPain.Series["Pain Areas"].Points[0]["Exploded"] = "True";
 mscPain.DataBind();
```

However, I get an "Index out of range" error when it hits the line:

```
mscPain.Series["Pain Areas"].Points[0]["Exploded"] = "True";
```

The examples I have seen have discretely plotted DataPoints, so I don't know if this is the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I'm an idiot.

```
            mscPain.DataSource = qCounts;
            mscPain.Series["Pain Areas"].XValueMember = "CategoryCouplet";
            mscPain.Series["Pain Areas"].YValueMembers = "Count";
            mscPain.Series["Pain Areas"]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Disabled";

            mscPain.DataBind();
            mscPain.Series["Pain Areas"].Points[0]["Exploded"] = "True";
```

Works - because I have now bound the data to the Chart.

Comment: You're not alone :) I also had my own moment of "whatta heck, I have no points here?" and figured out the chart wasn't bound yet. +1 :)